# Better way to declare multiple variables assigned to a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I'm looking for a shorter way to declare these variables:

```
const [nav, header, footer] = [getProps(data, ['nav']), getProps(data, ['header']), getProps(data, ['footer']) ];
```

I've tried this but it didn't work:

```
const [nav, header, footer] = getProps(data, ['nav','header', 'footer']);
```

the getProps function:

```
const getProps = (data, featureFlag) => {
    return get(data,`dataForServer.global.featureFlags.${featureFlag}`) ||
    false;
}
```

Comment: What's your getProps function?

Comment: @demkovych just updated the question with the function

Comment: You could use `const [nav, header, footer] = ['nav', 'header', 'footer'].map(v => getProps(data, v));`

Comment: @Elena as I understood, get if coming from lodash?

Comment: How can I make my code more unreadable. :)

Comment: @demkovych, yes, and it works as expected

Comment: well you send in an array and you do not use it as an array. The `getProps` would need a loop

Comment: @epascarello ok, I'll try to change it

Comment: You can save a few characters by not wrapping the right hand side in an array, and using simple variables on the left.   `const nav = getProps(...), header = getProps(...)` etc.  Not sure it's worth changing your nice simple function to wrap everything in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `getProps` function to return an array based on the flags passed to it:

```
const getProps = (data, featureFlag) => 
  featureFlag.map(ff => get(data,`dataForServer.global.featureFlags.${ff}`) || false);
```

You can then do:

```
const [nav, header, footer] = getProps(data, ['nav','header', 'footer']);
```